# Why is there a difference between "questions" and "search" in API?

Tags: bug, api-v2, questions, search

I have a query to find the number of questions tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) from `2012-08-01` to `2013-08-01`. Running this using both `/questions` and `/search` produces different results:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?todate=1387929600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--btTJ2LtJpU

`{"total":511058,"quota_remaining":245,"quota_max":300,"has_more":false}`

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?todate=1387929600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--btTJ2LtJpU

`{"total":540960,"quota_remaining":246,"quota_max":300,"has_more":false}`

Both queries are searching for the same questions over the same time interval; why do the results apparently differ?

Comment: is that two queries are supposed to give same result ?