# How to Create a Multi-tag URI Request to /questions

Tags: support, api, questions, tags

Just want to confirm if I'm doing this right. The  [/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) guide doesn't mention this.

Let's say I want to ask for multiple tags in one request, am I doing this right?

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=70&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=google-docs-api&tagged=firebase-database&tagged=android-sdk&tagged=google-drive-sdk&fromdate=1515888000
```

So basically what I'm doing is to chain multiple 'tagged=ACTUAL_TAG' together. I get a successful response but when I compare that in the "Stack Overflow search q" results,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=
```

I get varying results/responses - they're not exactly alike. Some of the questions from the  "Stack Overflow search q" are not found in my URI request. That's why I'm asking if I'm doing something wrong..

EDIT:
As answered below, the /search URI request did the trick for me as it allows "OR" tags where you chain tags together.

Comment: Almost/perhaps a duplicate of ["AND searching for tags"](https://stackapps.com/questions/1024/and-searching-for-tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the `/questions` doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions):

> ...use the tagged parameter with **a semi-colon delimited** list of tags. This is an **`and` contraint**(sic), **passing tagged=c;java** will return only those questions **with both tags**...

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

If you want questions that have ***either* tag**, use [the `/search` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) (or `/search/advanced`).

For example:
[/2.2/search?tagged=google-docs-api;firebase-database;android-sdk;google-drive-sdk...](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?fromdate=1515888000&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=google-docs-api%3Bfirebase-database%3Bandroid-sdk%3Bgoogle-drive-sdk&site=stackoverflow)

As for why the API sometimes differs from the website search, that has been asked a few times both here and elsewhere.  EG, see [Why is there a difference between "questions" and "search" in API?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4459/why-is-there-a-difference-between-questions-and-search-in-api).

But a common reason for API calls that use dates (`fromdate` etc.) to return unexpected results is not [taking into account how the API handles unix epoch time](https://stackapps.com/a/6670/7653).

Comment: Hey genius Brock, the /search route did it for me. Thanks a lot! HAHAHAHA do you have a 'buy me coffee' button link? :D

Comment: You're welcome. No coffee button, but there are these handy "upvote buttons" (where appropriate). ;)